# EFT generator circuit

Tags: switches, ltspice, high-voltage, emc, transient

I am simulating a circuit to model the EN 61000-4-4 waveform for electrical fast transients using LTspice. The idea is to have the generator for some in house testing.

After a lot of back and fourth with @Andy aka and @Tim Williams (special thank you to both of them) I decided to use the schematic of the generator provided by the test standard IEC61000-4-4.

[image]

After a few hours of figuring out the parameters I have somewhat of a satisfactory simulation.

This is my circuit, I am using an ideal switch and here is where my problem is. **I would like to have some help picking a good switch in order to get close to the standard's requirements.** ***In addition, if there are any suggestions to be made regarding my circuit, I welcome them.***
The following probing nodes have been added:  *EFT_output* / *Energy_storing_capacitor* / *Pulse*
[image]

Here are the results the probed nodes:

1. Energy_storing_capacitor, the capacitor has an initial voltage of 1000V
   [image]

The switch starts conducting with no delay :
[image]

This is the output voltage, the rise time is **221ps** due to the fact it is an ideal switch
[image]

As we can see the amplitude satisfies the requirements of the standard. [image]

Here is what the output looks like if an inductor is added
[image]

Here is the circuit with said inductor :
[image]

Comment: Now is the real tricky bit. Converting the switch into a lump of silicon that can produce a rise time of circa 6 ns is difficult. Maybe you should also add a waveform of one single pulse so that we can look at the rise time.

Comment: I agree, I thought getting the output voltage amplitude is hard... I wish I started with the circuit diagram proposed by the standard earlier... (you were right all along) 
Yes I can add the waveform here.

Comment: Dimitar, can you instead focus on the rise time of the pulse so we can see it in detail. Also, there are no axes scales so it's got no use as information.

Comment: @Andyaka Rise is probably about zero because an ideal SPICE switch was used. Yes, would like to see axes, and which node is being measured. And a label on the node so we can tell which it is. Note that we can't tell that 50/1000 ohm amplitudes have been respected, but the circuit should at least be doing something along those lines so that can be addressed more fully later and if necessary.

Comment: Sorry yes you are totally right... I will update the screenshot. Unfortunately, since the switch is ideal the rise time is in the picoseconds range

Comment: [This impressive looking document](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1876610211018741) shows an equivalent circuit that incorporates an inductor to get the right rise time (due to inter-wiring of 400 nH). Open the pdf and look at page 359 (only pages 355 to 360 are in the linked document)

Comment: An x scale in nano seconds starting at 0 would be good; you can pre-charge C1 to 1000 volts using the .IC command then start the switch at 0 ns. I think you need to add an inductor to make this realistic. See figure 7.

Comment: OK, looking better. The next bit is finding something to replace the switch. Something in the back of my mind tells me that a high-voltage xenon tube is really "fast" once triggered. I might be wrong and @TimWilliams 's viewpoint might be useful.

Comment: Okay I will wait for @TimWilliams reply. The reason for the inductor is simply to account for stray inducances?

Comment: Xenon is actually rather slow (~2us at best, with "simmering", IIRC)! Best gas discharge is hydrogen thyratron, probably. For this voltage, SiC MOSFETs will do.

Comment: @TimWilliams for the hydrogen thyratron is there a model i can find in LTspice? I guess the same for the SiC Mosfet? Is that a good option? https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MSC025SMA330#

Comment: Heh, I very highly doubt anyone's written a thyratron SPICE model.  Maybe for any kind of thyratron even. The basic behavior is similar to an SCR, but no SCR operates as quickly (and no realistic SPICE model will disagree).

Comment: I see, do you have any ideas what I can do to solve the problem? @TimWilliams

Comment: Y'know how to search distributors, right?

Comment: I have never done that  unfortunately :/

Answer (score 2):

Some approx. numbers. SiC MOSFET, reverse transfer capacitance 100 pF. Drain voltage 1000 V. Miller charge is thus 100 nC.

We need to fill this in 6 ns, so we need about 16 A of gate current.

If we have about 10 V of overdrive for the MOSFET gate, this means we will require a driver of about 0.6 ohm impedance.

A powerful commercial gate driver is almost suitable. Maybe it is suitable, if a FET with lower Cgd is used. Otherwise one could use 2 drivers in parallel, or make one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to solve this problem. I will gladly accept feedback, especially from the people that have worked with me so far (@Andyaka & @Tim Williams).

Due to the lack of inexpensive high voltage high speed power semiconductors on the market, trying to build a the power semiconductor switch using low voltage
power switches that are easily found on the market maybe a *solution*.
Since the big challenge is to achieve the 5ns rise time (or close to that...) specified on the standard for the output pulse, the possibility of using a high power switch topology with a Flyback power converter topology as the gate driver.

Here is the circuit : [image]

There are five operational stages of a proposed switch design.
In the first stage, energy is stored in the primary inductor when the driver switch is closed. In the second stage, the switch is opened and energy is sent to the gate input capacitance until the gate voltage reaches the zener voltage. The third stage occurs when the secondary inductor current continues to flow through the zener diode and load resistance, with the switch remaining closed. The fourth stage begins when the secondary inductor current is unable to maintain the load resistance voltage at the zener voltage, causing the switch to open after a fixed on-time. The fifth stage has no current flow.

Here are the simulations of the circuit :
[image]

here is the profile of one pulse : Lowest voltage is 7V, highest voltage is 250V.
To measure the rise time, we have **0.1*Vpeak = 25V** and **0.9*Vpeak= 225V**.
[image]

We can see that the pulse respects the standard as the rise time is just below 5ns, but of course this is an ideal case since there are no parasitics included,etc.

Comment: @Andyaka and do you have some comments?

Comment: @TimWilliams and do you have some comments?

Comment: You can save all that effort and not lose DC coupling by just using a TC4420, dude

Comment: I do not understand your point?

Comment: A flyback circuit can not supply reliable and stable gate voltage independent of gate charge (which varies from part to part) and is rate limited by the coupling factor (you will be hard pressed to find "k L1 L2 1" in practice). A gate driver is made specifically to drive gates, and they do quite well at it; that's why they make them.

Comment: So to drive the high voltage switch, you suggest I use TC4420... 
You do not believe that the gate driver method works?